# Как на php из таблицы вывести данные в json?

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
  $host = 'localhost';  // Хост, у нас все локально
  $user = 'user';    // Имя созданного вами пользователя
  $pass = 'password'; // Установленный вами пароль пользователю
  $db_name = 'test';   // Имя базы данных
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); // Соединяемся с базой

  // Ругаемся, если соединение установить не удалось
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
//get the data from table ‘books’
$query = "select * from ToDoList";
//execute the query
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
//$json_response = array();  
$posts = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($posts, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents('category.json', json_encode($posts, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
  ?>        
Код сохраняет данные в json файле. Как вывести данные из json на Frontend?
Как изменить код чтобы выдавал запрос типа site.kz/api/myresult?
На Frontend получаю данные так: fetch("http://seric0.kz/API/Todolist/category.json"), выдает ошибку:
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Comment: как связаны файлы `file_put_contents('myresult.json'` и `fetch("http://seric0.kz/API/Todolist/category.json"` ?

Comment: Никак, вот поэтому задал вопрос чтобы сделать правильный код. С PHP не знаком, но нужен backend

Comment: Изменил код, нужно получить категории

Comment: Добавьте перед строкой `echo json_encode($posts, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` строку: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

> Как вывести данные из json на Frontend?

PHP

```
file_put_contents('./API/Todolist/category.json', json_encode($posts, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  fetch('./API/Todolist/category.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json[0]));
</script>
```